# Disable navigation bar permanently

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I'm looking for a way to start Firefox (I'm using v46.0.1 - Windows and Linux) loading a predefined URL and with its navigation bar disabled/hidden without any option to bring navigation bar back using keyboard shortcuts or anything else besides restart it with different configuration!

Any suggestion on how doing that?

Comment: Without putting this in a programming context this sounds like it is about general computing, not programming.  As such: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: If this question is about programming, then please state so.  As always with Firefox add-ons, a good resource is to search for add-ons which do the exact thing you desire, or find one that is close see how they do what you want (e.g. [Hide Navigation Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hide-navigation-bar/)) Depending on the license for the add-on code, you can perhaps modify that code to do what you want.

Comment: You're right Makyen, it's not a programming matter. I've just posted the same question on Super User as you suggested. I'll get you second comment as a solution. Thanks